# Compile source file to a different directory?

Tags: java, directory-structure

Is there a way to compile a Java source file (`*.java`) to a different directory?

If my package file structure is like so:

```
Mathematics ->
  Formulas ->
    src ->
      // source files containing mathematical formulas...
    bin ->
      // class files containing mathematical formulas...
  Problems ->
    src ->
      // source files containing mathematical problems...
    bin ->
      // class files containing mathematical problems...
```

I want to separate source and class files to keep the folders organized, but I currently have to copy all the class files from the `src` folders to the `bin` folders after every compile.

Is there a way to simplify this process by compiling the class files to another folder in the `javac` command?

Comment: What directory do you want `bin`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yup, absolutely - use the `-d` option to specify the output directory:

```
javac -d bin src/foo/bar/*.java
```

Note that the directory you specify is the *root* of the output structure; the relevant subdirectories will be created automatically to correspond to the package structure of your code.

See the [javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for more details.

In this case you'd need to issue one `javac` command to compile the formulae, and another to compile the problems though - potentially using the formulae `bin` directory as part of the classpath when compiling the problems.

(You might want to consider using a single source structure but different packages, mind you. You should also consider using an IDE to hide some of this complexity from you - it ends up getting tiresome doing all of this by hand, even though it's not actually *hard*.)

Comment: How to compile entire src folder to bin ?

Comment: @Rushikesh: I would generally suggest using a build tool that will do this for you, e.g. Ant or Maven. You *could* just use `javac -d bin $(find src -name '*.java')` but that may run into problems if there are too many files.

Comment: @JonSkeet will that command in parentheses allow the class files to follow the hierarchy of source files ? like will ```com/github/johndoe/Main.java``` be places in ```bin/com/github/johndoe/Main.class```  ?

Comment: @AritroShome: No, the `-d bin` part would make sure it's in `bin/com/github/johndoe/Main.class`

Comment: @JonSkeet that's what I meant, I guess I left out the ```bin``` part ! Thanks !

Comment: @AritroShome: Even so, it doesn't follow the hierarchy of the source files - it follows the hierarchy of the *packages* declared in the source files. So you could have `src/Main.java` which declares `package com.github.johndoe;` and that would end up in `bin/com/github/johndoe/Main.class`

Comment: I meant package hierarchy only ! Oops, I seem to be lacking in communication. On a sidenote, @JonSkeet, any idea how to do that ```find``` on a Windows, possibly with a Makefile ?

Comment: @AritroShome: Please ask a new question - it's not really appropriate for a comment thread, particularly one over 8 years old.